# Mathematica freezes at 3DPlot

Tags: plotting, version-10

I am using Mathematica 10.1.
Mathematica constantly freezes on the first or the second attempt to display a 3D Graphic (Plot3D, ListPlot3D, Show..).

Here's a simple example

```
In[1]:=test = Plot3D[1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
                  BoxRatios -> Automatic, SphericalRegion -> True];

In[2]:=test
```

After calling the second line for a couple of times Mathematica hangs up. A message asking to disable dynamic updating appears after a while, but disabling has no effect.

There are also some other details and my thoughts:

- Everything worked just fine, then I didn't use Mathematica for about a month and the problem appeared.
- The problem arises with a different pieces of code.
- The problem seems to be connected with displaying 3D plots or dynamic updating.
- When Mathematica hangs up it does not drain a lot of memory or CPU, but it constantly requests more memory until the process is killed.

**UPD:** I have another observation: after some evaluations all of my variables just get cleared while they shouldn't. Didn't work out a rule when this happens though.

Comment: Do not be angry for my question, I take it you checked for viruses?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 8.1, @AlexeiBoulbitch  i am currently using windows defender, did not experience any problem with viruses in recent years. But may be you are right and it's worth a shot to download some Antivirus and run a full scan.

Comment: @icemtel Well, I have no experience with Win8, but such things as you write I had on the virus occasion. So I would recommend to check it.

Comment: Have you tried "clean starting" the frontend? Hold down the CONTROL+SHIFT keys while double clicking the Mathematica icon.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't help. 
@AlexeiBoulbitch I have scanned my PC with AVG, did not find any real threat.

Answer (score 1):

I am not absolutely sure, but it seems like updating Windows fixed the problem.